# Two JTables over each other

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager

As a part for my first GUI App I want to show 2 Tables the following way:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mq0m.jpg

I´m unable to print the 2 tables that way!
Here is my code so far:

```
// Center
JPanel panel_center = new JPanel();
panel_overview.add(panel_center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel_center.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel panel_center_table = new JPanel();
panel_center.add(panel_center_table, BorderLayout.NORTH);
panel_center_table.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
JPanel panel_table_north = new JPanel();
panel_center_table.add(panel_table_north);
JPanel panel_table_south = new JPanel();
panel_center_table.add(panel_table_south);
JPanel panel_center_combobox = new JPanel();
panel_center.add(panel_center_combobox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
panel_center_combobox.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel_center_combobox.add(combobox_table_chooser, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a different layout manager. I'd recommend using a [`BoxLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html), since you'll be able to easily stack components on top of each other. Here's a [How To Use BoxLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using a split pane. That way, the user can control the height of each of the tables.